# Turning high poly to low poly UV normal gone haywire

Tags: uv, normals, baking, topology

I am trying to make a low poly game character the high poly baked to my unwrapped low poly. I attached pictures of rendered and not rendered. Why is the rendered low poly colored like the normal map? Shouldn't it be the same color just with the light bending around it as I would expect? What did I do wrong? There isn't much stretching in the unwrap. I can't find any other examples that look the way my rendered image does.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to set the shading of the model to smooth and set the shading mode to GLSL.

Then you need to create a material and add the normal map texture in the texture panel. Then in *Image Sampling* section enable *Normal Map*, in *Influence* disable *Color* and in *Geometry* enable *Normal*

[image]

Comment: your advice helped. can you explain whats happening with the ears in this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8IObU.png. where is the orange and green colors on the UV map coming from? does it have to do with which way the normals are facing? or is my unwrap poor?

Comment: @JoshChenault Not sure, looks like flipped normals, try to select everything in edit mode and recalculate normals using ctrl+N and bake again.

Comment: I think i figured it out. when i decimated i lost too many vertices and it didnt match the high res model close enough. i add vertices and pushed points closer to the high res model and it looks better. http://imgur.com/7A2GJ6c

Comment: one thing i noticed was that i lost some volume from my high res to my low res. things like the shoulders neck lower legs etc are slightly smaller. any tips for this?